# Make Ctrl+C=copy and Ctrl+Shift+C=interrupt in VSCode terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, copy-paste

I'd like to have <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> copy and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (interrupt).

I figured out the first half

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+c",
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.copySelection",
    "when": "terminalFocus"
}
```

But how do I do the second half?  Is there a command to send an arbitrary key press to the terminal?

Comment: I found `sendText`, but it's not exported as a command.  Filed https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/31262.

Comment: Came here looking exactly for this, so thank you! But just realized that getting used to it has the potential of causing a lot of headache when working with regular terminals. Did you have problems?

Comment: @marcelocra I configure my terminal emulator to use these shortcuts, too.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

With Visual Studio Code 1.28.0 there is a command, `workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence`, to send arbitrary keypresses to the terminal.  See *[Send text from a keybinding to the terminal](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_send-text-from-a-keybinding)*.

```json
  {
    "key": "ctrl+shift+c",
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
    "args": {
      "text": "\u0003"
    },
    "when": "terminalFocus"
  }
```

Comment: You might be interested in how I am using it to interrupt, confirm and return with just ctrl+shift+c from anywhere which is otherwise annoying.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46899480/vscode-terminal-terminate-process-without-prompt

Comment: This works fine for local sessions, but over the SSH plugin it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: If you’re looking for a quick way to get here, it’s the `keybindings.json` file. Easily accessed via  “Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)”

Answer (score 30):

Answers above are all good. It took me long time to figure out exactly where to put these snippets. In **VSCode** go to **File** | **Preferences** | **Keyboard Shortcuts**. Switch to *json text view* by pressing small icon on top-right: **Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)** and edit setting file: keybindings.json

Example **keybindings.json**:

```json
// Place your key bindings in this file to override the defaults
[
    {
        "key": "ctrl+c",
        "command": "workbench.action.terminal.copySelection",
        "when": "terminalFocus"
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+v",
        "command": "workbench.action.terminal.paste",
        "when": "terminalFocus"
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+shift+c",
        "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
        "args": {
          "text": "\u0003"
        },
        "when": "terminalFocus"
    },
]
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer because it doesn't leave anything up to interpretation and "you figure it out where to insert these lines".

Comment: This answer is way better than accepted one.

Answer (score 6):

You can use Ctrl+C for both if you add a condition for text being selected in terminal. This way Ctrl+C copies only if text is selected, and sends SIGINT if no text is selected.

Add the following to ***keybindings.json***: `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`P` > `Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)`

```json
{
   "key": "ctrl+c",
   "command": "workbench.action.terminal.copySelection",
   "when": "terminalFocus && terminalProcessSupported && terminalTextSelected"
}
```

If you also want to make Ctrl+V work in terminal

```json
{
   "key": "ctrl+v",
   "command": "workbench.action.terminal.paste",
   "when": "terminalFocus && terminalProcessSupported"
},
```

Comment: yo! that's great! :-) I had to follow Rav's directions where to change settings.

Comment: Excellent. May I suggest adding `"when": "terminalFocus && terminalProcessSupported"` to the `ctrl+v` example, otherwise you may paste in the terminal when attempting to paste into an editor.

Answer (score 0):

These are the bindings that work for me on OSX, I use Karabiner to map my keyboard shortcuts like a Windows machine. So the control key is command.

```
[
{
    "key": "cmd+shift+c",
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.copySelection",
    "when": "terminalFocus"
},
{
    "key": "cmd+v",
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.paste",
    "when": "terminalFocus"
},
{
    "key": "cmd+c",
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
    "args": {
      "text": "\u0003"
    },
    "when": "terminalFocus"
},
]
```