# PowerShell console in Visual Studio Code: How to copy-paste?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, clipboard, copy-paste

I cannot Copy-Paste from the Visual Studio Code console. In ISE one can copy-paste some of the output, but it does not seem to be possible in Visual Studio Code Terminal. How can I copy-paste the output from the console when running PowerShell commands? I have the PowerShell Extension.

Comment: This should work fine by default. What particular methods for copying and pasting are you using, and what, specifically happens or doesn't happen?

Comment: @mklement0: I use the mourse and right clicking but the menu does not show. I have also tried to simply ctrl + c and see if I have the content in my clipboard but it does not work.

Comment: Right-clicking by itself should already copy selected text. If you prefer Ctrl+C (which by default interrupts the current command), have a look at [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45257525/7571258).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd> for copying / pasting work as-is in Visual Studio Code's integrated terminal.

By contrast, *right-click* behavior is *configurable*:

- On Windows, the default behavior is to copy, if text is currently selected, and paste otherwise - as in regular console windows.
- To get the same behavior as in the Windows PowerShell ISE, i.e. to instead show a *shortcut menu*, which contains `Copy` and `Paste` commands, add the following line to your `settings.json` file (before the closing `}`):

```
"terminal.integrated.rightClickBehavior": "default",
```

Alternatively, use the settings GUI (press <kbd>Ctrl+,</kbd>):

[image: right-click behavior setting]

Note:

- The screenshot was taken on macOS, where `selectWord` is the default setting; on Windows, it is `copyPaste`, with the behavior as described above.
- Also note the GUI's convenient search feature: typing `right click` in the search field was sufficient to locate the relevant setting.