# how to make the radian console stop listening to rendered output?

Tags: r, visual-studio-code, shiny, console, learnr

I use the radian console in VSCode.

To replicate my problem, run:

```
learnr::run_tutorial("Hello", package = "learnr")
```

The tutorial (which is basically a shiny app) pops up in a viewer and the output of the console is this:

```
Loading required package: shiny

Listening on http://127.0.0.1:7513
Browsing http://127.0.0.1:7513
```

All of this is perfectly fine, but:

The usual radian console `r$>` prompt disappears and I do not know how to get it back. Each time I have to close the current console and open a fresh instance.

I know that when rendering tutorials in RStudio, a "Job Output" Tab is opened in a seperate console, and i can stop the running Job (e.g. listening to the active shiny app) with a button.

How can I get back to interactive mode from "listening to job output mode"?

I tried different keypresses, tried to look up `radian` wiki and FAQ, looked for buttons in VSCode.

Comment: ctrl+c is how I usually quit a Shiny app in vscode using radian.

Comment: can confirm, it worked. On my mac, it is not cmd + c but literally ctrl + c. 

please make this an answer, so I can accept it. Thank you!

Comment: with my comment above I just wanted to give a hint to other mac users. a mac has both `ctrl` and `cmd` and it is often unclear which of these two is meant by a windows `ctrl`. therefore I used the word "literally". 
Thank you for even including how to change the key binding to `cmd + c`, even though this was not my request in the above comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default is `ctrl + c`.  However, if you want to change it, you can add the following to your [keybindings.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings):

```
    {
        "key": "Cmd+c",
        "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
        "args": {
          "text": "\u0003"
        },
        "when": "terminalFocus || (editorTextFocus && !editorHasSelection)"
    },
```

Notes:

1. The `Cmd+` bit is from the [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings). I don't have a Mac so I haven't tested it, but a similar command works on Windows.
2. `"\u0003"` is an escape sequence for [END OF TEXT](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0003/index.htm) that [sends an interrupt to the terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52735954/12545041).
3. The `when` clauses ensure the interrupt is sent only when you're in the terminal, or in the editor and do not have text selected. This is to avoid sending an interrupt when you're copy and pasting. You may wish to change the `when` clauses or add others - see more in the [when clause contexts docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/when-clause-contexts).