# Ctrl+C does not work on VS Code integrated terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, interrupt

I have VS Code installed on my macOS Mojave. The Ctrl+C command can work normally on my System Terminal (as on the right of the figure) to interrupt the current shell job in the foreground, but does not work on my VS Code integrated Terminal (as on the left of the figure).

[VS Code integrated Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sP3Vf.png)

Sometimes it appears like:

[VSCode integrated Terminal uncontrolled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mCcc.png)

My VS Code version: 1.78.0, OS: Darwin x64 18.7.0, Date: 2023-05-03T20:11:00.813Z (2 days ago)

It seems due to the `Date: 2023-05-03T20:11:00.813Z (2 days ago)`, as the behaviors started around one or two days ago, but I cannot figure things out.

I guess there is something wrong with my `settings.json`, but I did not touch to that at all. Can anyone help me to get the VS Code integrated Terminal back?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make Ctrl+C=copy and Ctrl+Shift+C=interrupt in VSCode terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45257525/make-ctrlc-copy-and-ctrlshiftc-interrupt-in-vscode-terminal)

Comment: @GROVER. I  opened the `keybindings.json` files and found no entry with key `ctrl+c`, how should I add such entry to indicate an `interrupt`?

Comment: @GROVER. There is also a strange thing, that two days ago, my terminal background is light yellow like the main screen. However, when this weird thing happened, the Terminal background also changed to white. Do you think they are related?